# Internet on the ethereum network

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

Excuse this if this is a dumb question. Would the whole internet at some scale be something we can put on the ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

This concept would be difficult to execute on the Ethereum blockchain because of the gas requirement, but there is a [recent project called SkyCoin that is working on this idea](https://cointelegraph.com/news/how-a-new-blockchain-based-project-is-trying-to-build-the-new-internet).

> To simplify, Skywire is described as ‘anonymous, decentralized mesh-Internet.’ The Skycoin Blockchain which powers it offers ‘free, instant and infinite transactions.’ And Skyminer is the ‘Internet access point that pays you for bandwidth.’ Excitingly, recent developments with Skyminer have allowed for a Net Neutrality solution; with 300 units to ship worldwide, it will enable a ‘user-controlled internet unaffected by a net neutrality repeal.’ Skycoin promise Skyminer will deliver high performance without excessive energy requirements and enable users to experience much faster Internet speeds that other ISPs.